# Data Binding causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, data-binding

I have two DataBindingClasses, say `Activity1Binding` and `Activity2Binding`. These are so because there are two different layouts in different packages. However, the logical functioning of both activities are the same so I am trying to make a super class.

**Superclass**

```
...
...
mBinding.setItem(item);
...
checkSolution(mBinding.getItem()); //many other methods that use mBinding.
```

**Activity 1** (extends Superclass)

```
...
Activity1Binding mBinding;
...
```

**Activity 2** (extends Superclass)

```
...
Activity2Binding mBinding;
...
```

I am facing the following problem.

To use `mBinding` in the super-class, it should have a reference to the object. Since all `DataBinding` objects extends `ViewDataBinding`, I tried to declare an object of the same and type-cast it to the specific object in the subclass.

**Superclass**

```
ViewDataBinding mBinding;
...
```

**Activity 1**

```
mBinding = (Activity1Binding) DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity1);
```

*Problem*: This will not allow me to use methods like `getItem()` which are specific to the databinding. I have used the same object name `item` in both binding layouts.

How should I go about creating a super class that will let me bind to both objects and at the same time let me remove redundant code from both classes?

Comment: any update on this? Running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create private field `ViewDataBinding mBinding` in super class.

Create getter for that field

`protected ViewDataBinding getViewDataBinding(){
    return mBinding
}`

Also, create abstract method that will provide you layout resource id i.e. **getLayoutId()** and override it in child classes with actual layout ids.

In onCreate() of the super class, do the actual binding using `DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, **getLayoutId()**, container, false)`.

After that, you create `binding` field in your child class and assign it value  via getter of the `mBinding`.
Only thing you need to do is to cast it to your specific binding class.
Something like: `binding = (Activity1Binding) getViewDataBinding()`